# Convert VB to C# error Application.StartupPath

Tags: c#, vb.net

I converted code from VB:

```vb
Module Module1
    Public strPath = Application.StartupPath & "\"

    Public Sub LoadUserControl(ByVal obj As Object, ByVal uc As System.Windows.Forms.UserControl)
        obj.Controls.Clear()
        uc.Left = (obj.Width - uc.Width) / 2
        uc.Top = (obj.height - uc.Height) / 2 - 10
        obj.Controls.Add(uc)
    End Sub
End Module
```

to this C# code:

```
static class Module1
{
    public static  strPath = Application.StartupPath + "\\";

    public static void LoadUserControl(object obj, System.Windows.Forms.UserControl uc)
    {
        obj.Controls.Clear();
        uc.Left = (obj.Width - uc.Width) / 2;
        uc.Top = (obj.height - uc.Height) / 2 - 10;
        obj.Controls.Add(uc);
    }
}
```

I got error at `strPath` :

> System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath' is a property but is used like a type

What could I do to solve this?

Comment: You haven't provided a type for 'strPath'.  The original VB code implicitly used 'Object' for the type - you need to do this explicitly in C# (and you can't use 'var' since that's only for local variables).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `dynamic` keyword in C# to simulate VB's weak typing:

```
static class Module1
{
    public static string strPath = System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath + "\\";

    public static void LoadUserControl(dynamic obj, System.Windows.Forms.UserControl uc)
    {
        obj.Controls.Clear();
        uc.Left = (obj.Width - uc.Width) / 2;
        uc.Top = (obj.Height - uc.Height) / 2 - 10;
        obj.Controls.Add(uc);
    }
}
```

In this example the `obj` variable is declared as dynamic in order to allow calling properties and methods at runtime. Also notice that you should provide a type for the `strPath` static variable which in this case is `string`.

Alternatively if you know that `obj` will be a UserControl you'd better use strong typing which will provide you with compile time safety:

```
static class Module1
{
    public static string strPath = System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath + "\\";

    public static void LoadUserControl(System.Windows.Forms.UserControl obj, System.Windows.Forms.UserControl uc)
    {
        obj.Controls.Clear();
        uc.Left = (obj.Width - uc.Width) / 2;
        uc.Top = (obj.Height - uc.Height) / 2 - 10;
        obj.Controls.Add(uc);
    }
}
```

Comment: If in myproject, I didnt use UserCtrol, instead I only used Forms, so How coud I fix code?
 public static void LoadUserControl(System.Windows.Forms.UserControl obj, System.Windows.Forms.UserControl uc)
    {
        obj.Controls.Clear();
        uc.Left = (obj.Width - uc.Width) / 2;
        uc.Top = (obj.Height - uc.Height) / 2 - 10;
        obj.Controls.Add(uc);
    }